# Update field only if document updated in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am calling `findAndModify()` using the `$max` function to set the value of a field to the largest value.

For example, as shown in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/max/).

```
db.scores.update( { _id: 1 }, { $max: { highScore: 950 } } )
```

I'd like to also set a `lastUpdatedTimestamp` only if the document is updated. I can't just perform a `$set` because that will always change the last updated timestamp. Is there a good mechanism within MongoDB to set another value *only if* the document is updated? Something similar to `$setOnInsert` but for any update.

---

If there isn't what might be a good approach here? Right now I'm thinking I could perform a regular find. Then do a local comparison. If the new value is greater than the old, then there is a good possibility that the update will update the document. So I just include the `$set` for the `lastUpdatedTimestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

You can first make a query to find records having highScore less than your input value and then update. This will only set lastUpdatedTimestamp on updating the record.

```
db.scores.findAndModify({
   query: { highScore: { $lt: 950 } },
   update: { $set: { "highScore" : 950, "lastUpdatedTimestamp" : new Date() } },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

as  I  see  you wanted  to . update  your document  only  if  your `highScore`  can be  updated .

only  the  documents's  score  is  lower than  new  score  value  ,it will be  updated  with  `score`  field  and  `lastUpdatedTimestamp`

the best way  is  put  your  new  score  in the filter  to  find  the documents  match  old score  < new score

do it  like this

```
db.scores.update(
{_id :4,highScore:{$lt:900}},
{$set:{highScore:900},
$currentDate: { lastModified: true }})
```

or  set the modify time like

```
{$set:{highScore:900 ,lastupdatetime: new_time},
```

Comment: I tried this out. However, I'm trying to use `findAndModify`. So if I include the conditional and the current `highScore` is greater than the possible update value, Mongo won't return any existing document since it didn't find it.

Comment: `findAndModify() ` will Only  return the documets can be  modify  in your  query . what  you wanted to return .